# How to use for loop in Subprocess.run command

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I'm using `subprocess.run` to run a command that has a for loop in it but not getting back the expected result. Here's a simplified case that shows the issue.
In bash shell:

`for i in {1..3}; do echo ${i}; done`

The result is:

```
1
2
3
```

Which is what I expect and want. However in my code when I execute this following:

`subprocess.run("for i in {1..3}; do echo ${i}; done", shell=True, check=True)`

the result printed on my shell is `{1..3}`

But what I want the result to be is:

```
1
2
3
```

like when I execute the code in my shell.
Would appreciate any insights on how to fix this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using subprocess.popen:

```
from subprocess import popen
process = subprocess.Popen("bash for i in {1..3}; do echo $i; done")
try:
    outs, errs = process.communicate(timeout=15)
except TimeoutExpired as e:
    process.kill()
    outs, errs = process.communicate()
```

Or, using your original line of code:

```
subprocess.run("bash for i in {1..3}; do echo $i; done", shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True)
```

I was able to gleam this information from the subprocess doc's located here: [Subprocess Pypi Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Regards, and I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Not a problem at all!

Comment: I'm getting:  No such file or directory: 'bash for i in {1..3}; do echo ${i}; done'

Comment: This gives me `Syntax error: "do" unexpected`

Comment: the issue is at the string interpolation, ill update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to spawn a subshell:

```
subprocess.run("sh -c 'for i in {1..3}; do echo ${i}; done'", shell=True, check=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this still gave me the ```{1..3}``` result again. Did this give you the ```1  2  3``` result?

Answer (score 0):

In case of python3:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.getoutput("""for i in {1..3}; do echo ${i}; done""")
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, this still gives me the ```{1..3}``` result. Did this give you the ```1  2  3``` result?