# for loop in `Subprocess.run` results in `Syntax error: "do" unexpected`

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I'm trying to run a `for` loop in a shell through python. `os.popen` runs it fine, but is deprecated on 3.x and I want the stderr. Following the highest-voted answer on [How to use for loop in Subprocess.run command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56122270/how-to-use-for-loop-in-subprocess-run-command) results in `Syntax error: "do" unexpected`, with which shellcheck concurs:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.run(
    "bash for i in {1..3}; do echo ${i}; done",
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, )

print(proc.stderr)
```

I'm ultimately trying to reset all usbs by calling this shell code https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611305/362437 through python, so any alternate approaches to doing that would be appreciated too.

Comment: There's no need to involve bash (or any shell, for that matter) to do what you have linked. Python is perfectly capable of writing ("``echo >``") to a file as well.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi good to know, I'll go that route unless this gets an answer

Comment: I find that ``os.popen`` is not deprecated: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.html#os.popen

Comment: Of course, you don't need Bash for this simple example. `for i in 1 2 3` does the same thing in the Bourne shell. It's hard to think of situations where a shell loop would be preferable over a Python loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
subprocess.run('foo', shell=True)
```

it actually runs the equivalent of

```
/bin/sh -c 'foo'
```

(except that it magically gets all quotes right :-) ). So, in your case, it executes

```
/bin/sh -c "bash for i in {1..3}; do echo ${i}; done"
```

So the "command" given with the [`-c`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash) switch is actually a [list](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Lists) of three commands: `bash for i in {1..3}`, `do echo ${i}`, and `done`. This is going to leave you with a very confused shell.

The easiest way of fixing this is probably to remove that `bash` from the beginning of the string. That way, the command passed to /bin/sh makes some sense.

If you want to run bash explicitly, you're probably better off using `shell=False` and using a list for the first argument to preserve your quoting sanity. Something like

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.run(
    ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'for i in {1..3}; do echo ${i}; done'],
    shell=False,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, )
```

Comment: Awesome -- that would answer the linked question as well, which currently has no working answers.

Comment: I'll vote for closing that as a dupe of this and see what happens. =)