# Error while executing bash for loop from python subprocess

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I want to run this command from python mentioned [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#protocol):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./*.wav; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done) -c copy output.wav
```

But i can't even run this:

```
subprocess.run('for i in {1..3}; do echo $i; done'.split(), capture_output=True)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/russich555/hdd/Programming/Freelance/YouDo/21.intercom_record/test.py", line 36, in <module>
    pr = subprocess.run(
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 546, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1022, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1899, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'for'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

**Also** **tried** add `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.run('for i in {1..3}; do echo $i; done'.split(), capture_output=True, shell=True)
```

*stderr output:*

```
i: 1: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

---

**Also** **tried** pass `/bin/bash`, because [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) says that `shell=True` using `/bin/sh`

```
subprocess.run('/bin/bash for i in {1..3}; do echo $i; done'.split(), capture_output=True)
```

*stderr output:*

```
/bin/bash: for: No such file or catalog
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [for loop in \`Subprocess.run\` results in \`Syntax error: "do" unexpected\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71472237/for-loop-in-subprocess-run-results-in-syntax-error-do-unexpected)

Comment: When using `shell=True` do *not* use `"some bash command".split()`.

Comment: Also, separately, plain `split` is wrong; if you need to split a command line, use `shlex.split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors here, or really, three;

- You are trying to use shell features without `shell=True`
- You are trying to use Bash features, but the default shell on non-Windows platforms is POSIX `sh`; you can fix that with `executable='/bin/bash'` (obviously, adjust the path if necessary).

More fundamentally, though, you want to avoid using a subprocess when Python can perform the loop natively.

```
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess

subprocess.run(
    ['ffmpeg', '-f', 'concat', '-safe', '0',
     '-i', '/dev/stdin', '-c', 'copy', 'output.wav'],
    input="".join(f"file '{x}'\n" for x in Path.cwd().glob("*.wav")),
    text=True, capture_output=True)
```

Relying on `/dev/stdin` for the input file is somewhat platform-dependent; in the worst case, you'll need to refactor to use a temporary file, or fall back to using the shell after all.

```
subprocess.run(r"""ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" $PWD/*.wav) -c copy output.wav""",
    shell=True, executable='/bin/bash',
    text=True, capture_output=True)
```

As noted in comments, you should either use `shell=True` and pass in a single string as the first argument for the shell to parse, or else pass in a list of tokens without `shell=True` and with no shell features like wildcard expansion, command substitution, variable interpolation, redirection, shell builtins, etc etc.

If you really wanted to explicitly run Bash, the syntax for that would look like

```
subprocess.run(
    ['bash', '-c',
     r"""ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(printf "file '%s'\n" $PWD/*.wav) -c copy output.wav"""],
    text=True, capture_output=True)
```

(The syntax `bash for loop etc` tries to find a file named `for` and run it with Bash, passing in `loop` and `etc` as arguments.)

It's not clear why you are using `capture_output=True` here; in order for that to be useful, you need to examine the `.stdout` (and/or perhaps `.stderr`) attributes of the object returned by `subprocess.run`. If you just want to discard the output, use `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL`

Comment: For more, perhaps see my top-voted answer and/or [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in `subprocess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: If `ffmpeg` supports `ffmpeg -i -` for reading from standard input, using `-` instead of `/dev/stdin` should be portable and robust. Alas, I'm not in a place where I can test this. (You could then use `printf "file '%s'\n" $PWD/*.wav | ffmpeg -i -` to avoid the Bash process substitution syntax; this should work with any `sh`.)

Comment: thanks a lot! I red your 3 answers about `subprocess` and most likely will read them again